# How to change the limit quotas per day for Place API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

There are a quotas for Place API per day is 2400, anybody how to increase this limit ?

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#set-caps) is indicated how you can change that quota.